# How to compile SCSS with PostCSS in gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp, postcss

I have two legacy projects which share lot's of common functionality, so I'm trying to make them dry and move code into separate package.

I written some SCSS for one (which uses webpack), then included that css in another, and got

```
[13:18:52] postcss-partial-import: /home/bunyk/../node_modules/FEGeneric/src/user/auth.scss:26:26: Unknown word

  24 |             background-color: #CC4815;
  25 |             img {
> 26 |                 width: #{$panel-width / 2};
     |                          ^
  27 |                 display: block;
  28 |                 height: 550px;
```

This was fixed by adding

```
import scss_syntax from 'postcss-scss';
```

into my gulp task, which currently looks like this:

```
gulp.task('styles:debug', cb =>
        gulp.src('app/styles/application.scss')
            .pipe(rename({extname: '.css'}))
            .pipe(sourcemap.init())
            .pipe(postcss([
                require('postcss-partial-import')({extension: 'scss'}),
                require('postcss-nested'),
                require('postcss-sassy-mixins'),
                require('postcss-inline-comment'),
                require('postcss-simple-vars'),
                require('postcss-conditionals'),
                autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']})
            ], {
                syntax: scss_syntax // <--- this was added
            }))
            .on('error', e => {
                gutil.log(e.message);
                cb();
            })
            .pipe(sourcemap.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
);
```

Now project compiles successfully, but in the browser I see raw SCSS: 
[image]

In the postcss-scss readme I see statement in bold "This module does not compile SCSS", but now my question is: **"Which module does?"**

Answer (score 2):

There is a gulp task,[gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass), that will compile your scss down to CSS and then you can pipe it into post-css. I do this regularly with Autoprefixer.

Comment: Looks like I was mislead by gulp-scss module, which requires scss to be installed (and I want everything to be installed by npm, for simplicity.

Anyway, even gulp-sass did not helped, because regardless before or after postcss in pipeline it gives me syntax errors. :(

Comment: I don't personally know of a sass module for a task runner that doesn't require sass to be installed somewhere else. It looks like you could install [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) though with npm and make gulp-scss work while maintaining all of your package management in npm.